# Converting fields to date gives datetime values

Tags: sql, date, datetime, mariadb

**Context:**

MariaDB 5.5.68.

I have to convert VARCHAR fields containing dates into regular formatted date (as [DATE Format from MariaDb Documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date/)).

Here is how i proceed:

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE
ADD FORMATED_DATE DATE;

UPDATE MYTABLE
SET FORMATED_DATE = UNFORMATED_DATE ;

SELECT FORMATED_DATE, UNFORMATED_DATE  
FROM MYTABLE
```

[image: Result from last Sql Command]

The conversion is ok but FORMATED_DATE field is more like a DATETIME to me than a DATE, according to documentation. Is that normal because i don't want to deal with the time part of these dates in the application using this field.

Comment: What application did you use to display that result? It might be just the way the application displays `DATE` type.

Comment: I used TOAD 8.00.296. And indeed, when the select query is run on the server, the DATE fields are correctly displayed.
Thanks for this smart suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try like this?

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE
ADD FORMATED_DATE DATE;

UPDATE MYTABLE
SET FORMATED_DATE = DATE_FORMAT(UNFORMATED_DATE, '%d/%m/%Y')

SELECT FORMATED_DATE, UNFORMATED_DATE  
FROM MYTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

it makes no sense, to have two date columns  in the first place as they show the same content.

You format the date only when you select the data and you **not** keep it that way in the database.

The original data has stil teh possibiliy to use date/time functions and the first has not.

You can use [DATE_FORMAT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date_format/) to get almoszt any format you want and need, so please use it and don't save redundant data in your database

> ```
> CREATE tABLe mytable (mydate date)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('2019-01-28')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(mydate,'%d/%m/%Y') FROM mytable
> ```
>
> ```
> | DATE_FORMAT(mydate,'%d/%m/%Y') |
> | :----------------------------- |
> | 28/01/2019                     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=43abc6712091b374465b5bf4ca0cc548)*

Comment: I used two date columns only for testing and monitoring the conversion.

Comment: then use the date_format as i explained, i am not sure if the dates you generate will work on all systems.